# POST method to Rails API

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, post

How to send POST message to Rails app (from outside the app)?

I've been looking for an answer for a week now and this already becomes tiresome.

I'm trying to send POST method to my rails app form iOS app. However nothing happen. I get no reply and nothing gets done. I don't even get an error.

Here's my standard Objective-c code (even if you're unfamiliar with it it's pretty descriptive):

```
NSMutableString *post = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"{'my_token': '34252345random235543252b', 'recipient_name': 'James', 'sender_message':'hello'}"];


NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somethingurl.herokuapp.com/app_send_message_post"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

GET method, however, works like a charm.

```
NSString* tokenString = @"122131hjrandom32fg1jh3f134";
    NSString* cleanTokenString = [tokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString* userNameString = @"James";
    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somethingurl.herokuapp.com/app_send_message?my_token=%@&recipient_name=%@&sender_message=hello", cleanTokenString, userNameString];
     //NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://fast-peak-2994.herokuapp.com/app_send_message?my_token=%@", cleanTokenString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

Here's my rails code somewhat simplified to show the point:

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :blocks
  resources :users
  resources :messages

  root to: 'messages#index'

  match '/app_send_message' => 'messages#app_get_send_message', via: :get
  match '/app_send_message' => 'messages#app_post_send_message', via: :post
....
```

messages_controller.rb

```
def app_get_send_message
   render text: 'this is get method'
end

def app_post_send_message
   render text: 'this is post method'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you should disable CSRF token verification. This generally protects Rails apps from sending forged post requests from automated scripts. Of course, when using Rails as an API provider, this doesn't work correctly.

Check your ApplicationController for the protect_from_forgery call and remove it. More details here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I tried it but I still get no response. The response itself is not so important itself, I just want to know whether app_post_send_message action was called or not.

Comment: You can test that out by doing something like Rails.logger.info "I was called". This will show up either in the Webbrick output (if running in interactive mode) or the development.log or production.log (depending on your environment).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be looking at the [rails-api project](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) which handles a bunch of API related problems. It specifically mentions the problems with `protect_from_forgery` in the default Rails installation.